# MVC 5 unobtrusive validation without having a Form tag in Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

Following is the subset of my Razor View

```
@model StudentViewModel

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
</div>
```

I don't have `@Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm` in my View. I am posting this data to Controller / Action with Jquery Ajax.

Now the issue is i want to validate [Required] constraint and display error message if it fails. I am wondering how can I achieve MVC 5 unobtrusive validation in this scenario.

-> Not having a form tag is intentional as I am using Kendo Grids in my View and constructing ViewModel to Post in Javascript.

Comment: You cannot (if you insect the source code you will see that no `data-val-*` attributes are added if there is no form tag). Just wrap the controls in `<form> ..... </form>` (you can still have the tags even though your using ajax.